# video.js not working properly with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, video.js

I am trying to use video.js(gitHub link - https://github.com/videojs/video.js ) plugin in my jquery mobile project to get custom video player, I followed all the documentation from this site (http://videojs.com/), but due to some reasons I am getting following errors -

1. The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs).
2. this[a] is not a function.

My code -

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="Js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <link href="mcss/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css"   rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        videojs("Mobile_VIDEO_1").ready(function () {
            var vid = this;
            vid.on("ended", function () {
                alert("is");
                $("#videoListXYZ").css("display", "block");
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="p-forget-password">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content ui-body-cf ui-responsive">
            <!-- inserted dyanamically using handlebars template "http://handlebarsjs.com"/ -->
            <video id="Mobile_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-id="{{VideoId}}" data-setup='{ "plugins" : { "resolutionSelector" : { "default_res" : "360" } } }' autoplay="autoplay" width="340" height="250">
                <source src="{{Path}}" type="video/mp4" data-res="360" />
            </video>                  
        </div>                                 
    </div>
</body>
```

Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong.

-I tried using putting videojs(xyx).ready(....) inside document.ready
- I also tried sending my script at the bottom of my page as suggested by (http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/985-api-ready-call-fails), but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

After many hit and trial, I realized that my event is firing much before the DOM initialization, so I searched for how to check when the whole page is fully loaded and I come across this document (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/run-javascript-only-after-entire-page-has-loaded/)  from this link I used this

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

to check if my page is fully loaded or not .  my final solution is mentioned below , if any of you come across a better solution then please share that to help others.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    var videoPath = $('#sv1').attr('src');    //to get the path of video
    if (videoPath != "" && videoPath != null) { //checking for non-empty path
        console.log(videoPath);
        videojs('MY_VIDEO_1', { "plugins": { "resolutionSelector": { "default_res": "360" } } }, function () {
            console.log('Good to go!');
            this.play();
            this.on('ended', function () {
                console.log('awww...over so soon?');
                $("#videoList").css("display", "block");
            });
        });
        $("#replay").click(function () {
            var myPlayer = videojs("MY_VIDEO_1");
            myPlayer.play();
        });
    }
});
```